# Editing fstab for a new drive that will contain subdirectories on other disks

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, fstab

Currently the disks on my box look like this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       30G   28G  174M 100% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                      4.7T  3.0T  1.5T  67% /testdrive
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1      99M   30M   65M  32% /boot
tmpfs                  63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/mapper/mpath2p1  4.5T  1.5T  2.8T  34% /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/data
/dev/mapper/mpath3p1  1.5T  674G  762G  47% /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/index
/dev/mapper/mpath4p1   92G   31G   57G  35% /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/undo
/dev/mapper/mpath5p1  276G  151G  111G  58% /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/temp
```

I've been asked to add a new disk `/testdrive2/main`. The problem is, if I add a new one like that won't it take over and only show that drive and not show any of the other drives that essentially will become sub directories of /testdrive2/main?

fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/mpath2p1    /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/data ext4  defaults 0 0
/dev/mapper/mpath3p1    /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/index ext4       defaults       0                                0
/dev/mapper/mpath4p1    /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/undo ext4        defaults       0                                0
/dev/mapper/mpath5p1    /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/temp ext4        defaults       0                                0
#/dev/mapper/mpath6p1   /testdrive2/main/    ext4 defaults   0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add /testdrive2/main mountpoint before its subdirs (e.g right after procfs)
- Ensure that /testdrive2/main/db/apps_st/ folder exists in /testdrive2/main mountpoint